# Manually log the App Install event using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm integrating the Facebook SDK into my Android app for the purposes of tracking app installs via Facebook ads. The documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#7--add-app-events) explains that the "App Install", "App Launch" and "In-App Purchase" events are automatically logged. It also mentions that automatic logging can be disabled, in which case the above events can be logged manually.

I don't want "App Launch" events to be logged, so I've chosen to disable automatic logging. However, nowhere in the documentation does it explain how (or where) to log the "App Install" event. I've checked in Facebook's `AppEventsConstants` class but there is no install-related event.

The iOS SDK/documentation has the exact same problem.

Has anyone tried to do this and/or been successful? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, did you got any solution?

Comment: @Izzuddiin Sadly not; in the end I just went with automatic logging and haven't looked at it since.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. I don`t want Purchase event to be logged automatically since I have other payment gateways active apart from Google In-App . I am handling those manually. Since I am updating to v5 the events are automatically sent and if i switch it off then i will lose App Install and App Launch events which i need. How to solve this ?

Comment: @GlennPorter? Any Update?

Comment: @binaryKarmic I never got to the bottom of this. I went with automatic logging in the end. I've moved company now and so never sorted it out. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this, you can log an event named
`fb_mobile_first_app_launch` which has an optional param named `fb_auto_published` (I think this means if it is automatic or manual). This gets translated into app install.

If you want app activations/launches/opens log the event `fb_mobile_activate_app` with an optinal param `fb_mobile_launch_source` (you can set to `Unclassified` if you don't care)

Comment: Also, I found that if I wanted the `fb_mobile_first_app_launch` event to show as "Automatically logged" in the Facebook Events Manager (https://www.facebook.com/events_manager2) then I had to add a parameter called `_implicitlyLogged` with a value of 1.